# PL/SQL set a link as default at the begining of the script

Tags: oracle, plsql, dblink

I need to select a link at the beginning in the script. Usually we do select links as below,

```
begin
select * from v$database@linkname;
end;
```

But now I need to select the link at the beginning something like this,

```
begin
select_link 'linkname';
select * from v$database;
end;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> select * from v$database@linkname;

You cannot simply have a **SELECT** statement like that in **PL/SQL**. It expects an **INTO** clause.

If I understand correct;y, you want to parameterize the **DATABASE LINK**. I am afraid you need to (ab) use **dynamic SQL**.

For example,

```
SQL> var cur refcursor
SQL> DECLARE
  2    var_link varchar2(20);
  3  BEGIN
  4  var_link:='@your_db_link';
  5    OPEN :cur FOR 'SELECT * FROM dual'||var_link;
  6    END;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print cur

D
-
X

SQL>
```